# Archive threads based on how old is the last message in the thread

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using Google Apps Script to archive all the emails that are in the inbox and are labeled "follow up".

This works - but I have a problem.

The threads (conversations) are archived based on the 1st/oldest email in the thread - while I need it to be archived based on the last/latest email in the thread.
What I basically want is - "if there was no reply to the thread for 4 days - archive it".

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what way you get the list of threads from one email (order by) but you can compare all threads to find the last one. If this date is older than 4 days then you can set it a label in order to archive it.

Is that what you are looking for? I am not sure. I work with Java.

Comment: Does doesn't really help,

I'm talking about a case where I have a single thread, which contains several emails (back and forth replies) - and google search "older_than" returns the results based on the oldest email in the thread - and not the newest email - which is the latest reply.

var threads = GmailApp.search('label:aaafollowup older_than:14d');